# How to pass runtime parameter like base URL in retrofit with hilt And How to pass base URL from repository?

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, retrofit, dagger-hilt

-This is the Network Module class where I want to add a parameter of URL dynamically at runtime for my retrofit builder. And that URL I want to pass from repository.

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class NetworkModule{
@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesRetrofit(): Retrofit {
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    okHttpClient.apply {
        addInterceptor(interceptor)
        connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
    val client: OkHttpClient = okHttpClient.build()
    return Retrofit.Builder().client(client).baseUrl(**url**)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesFakerAPI(retrofit: Retrofit): FakerAPI {
    return retrofit.create(FakerAPI::class.java)
}
```

Comment: You should create a provider method to get it. What do you mean by "pass from repository"? If you add the class maybe I can help you